# constantly update variable with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

i'm changing a string by moving each letter over ("a" becomes "b", "z" becomes "a") using a for loop, but each time the function loops, it doesn't store the new value. when ABC is supposed to get "BCD", I get the function to loop "BBC, ACD, ABD"

I'm new to coding and I am positive that there's an easier way to do this (it's classified as easy on the coderbyte challenges) but I'd like to try and solve it this way since it's the one that I came up with.

Hints > Answers. The longer I'm stuck on this the more determined I am to make this code work haha especially because I feel so close!

```js
function moveLetter(str) {
  var index = ["a","b","c"..."z", "a"] //sorry didn't want to type out the whole alphabet and my code just crashed
  var alpha = "zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  var new = ""
  
  for (c=0; c<=str.length-1; c++) {
    if (str.charAt(c) == " ")
      str.charAt(c) == " "; //I did this to circumvent the "undefined" error I would get when the loop hits a space
    
    else
      str = str.replace(str.charAt(c), index[alpha.search(str.charAt(c)))];

}

return str
}
```

yes this is an ugly Frankenstein of code to do something relatively simple.

My idea was to have the loop go through each character of a given string and replace it based on an indexed array I made.

The core question (besides why I'm doing it this way) is "how do I get the variable to maintain the change after the first loop so it looks like this:

ABC -> BBC -> BCC - > BCD

Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: `var new = ""` should throw an error.

Comment: You may be interested in [`String.prototype.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) and [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode). The first gives you the numeric code for a character in a string, and the second gives you a string from a character code. With those, you can shift characters with simple arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'string';  // Call toLowerCase if needed

var length = str.length;

var START_CHAR_CODE = 97;
var END_CHAR_CODE = 122;

var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

  var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
  
  if (code === END_CHAR_CODE) {
    code = START_CHAR_CODE;
  } else {
    code++;
  }
  
  output.push(String.fromCharCode(code));

}

alert(output.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Always** keep it **plain** and **simple**! According to your code: You **only** need a **string** with the alphabet. An **array** is **unnecessary**. In

`var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`

every letter is in lower case. To compare the string, first set it to **lower case**:

`var str = str.toLowerCase()`.

Next, check the **last letter "z"**. This should be **"a"**:

```
if(str[i] == "z") {
    result += "a"; 
}
```

With the string method **search**, we get the **index** of the matching value in the string. Here we need the **index behind**:

`alpha.search(str[i]) + 1`.

From this index, we want the letter:

`alpha.charAt(alpha.search(str[i]) + 1)`.

Complete:

```
function moveLetter(str) {
    var str = str.toLowerCase(); // every character to lower case 
    var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var result = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
        if(str[i] == "z") {
            result += "a";
        } else {
            result += alpha.charAt(alpha.search(str[i]) + 1);
        }
    }
    return result.toUpperCase(); // upper case
    // return result;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amwiom/p8gcwkoc/)